# How to get XP-Pen Star 06 to work

Tags: drivers, software-installation, xorg, tablet, graphics-tablet

I bought an [xp-pen star 06](http://www.xp-pen.com/goods/show/id/194.html) drawing tablet. I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and I installed DIGImend kernel and am following instructions found [here on the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TabletSetupWizardpen) but I cannot seem to make it work properly. It seems I failed to install the driver/configuration as I cannot find configuration file located in

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-wizardpen.conf
```

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I am using the drivers downloaded from [here on xp-pen.com](https://www.xp-pen.com/download/index) for my XP-Pen star 3 product.

Select your device, and download the Linux driver (the zip file) from the page that comes up.

Then just extract the files in a folder with a simple name and execute the `Pentablet_Driver.sh` file to install.